# hibernate's size function produces sql that fails in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql, oracle11g

When hibernate parses out this hql:

```
UPDATE VERSIONED Person SET groupsCount = followingGroup.size WHERE id = :id
```

it generates this sql:

```
UPDATE Person
  SET version  =version+1,
  groupsCount=
  (SELECT COUNT(followingg1_.followerId)
     FROM GroupFollower followingg1_
    WHERE Person.id=followingg1_.followerId
  )-1
  WHERE id IN
  (SELECT groupfollo2_.followerId
     FROM GroupFollower groupfollo2_
    WHERE groupfollo2_.followingId=?
  )
```

That query fails at the "-1" after the subquery for the count of the followingids. If i take out the "-1" it runs just fine, or if i move the "-1" to "SELECT COUNT(followingg1_.followerId) - 1" it also works.

I don't see how to work around this, short of using db specific sql, is this a bug with 11g?

Comment: Wow, I do not understand how that hql was traslated to this sql. Am I missing something. Where is the -1 coming from.

Comment: yeah, well it looks like "followingGroup.size" is getting the matching records in the fkeyed groupfollower table, which has a followingGroup column. from there, i assume that maybe thats returning the wrong starting index for what hibernate thinks it should (1 vs 0), so is then subtracting 1 to get the right "size".




what i really dont get, is why that query fails, i know oracle sql pretty well, i dont understand why it can't run that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the problem, I was wrong, that statement deals with a "Person" object, which is more complicated that I first realized, although it was at that line that the test was failing, it was actually hql in the class it was testing that produced the sql that was the problem.

```
UPDATE VERSIONED Person SET groupsCount = followingGroup.size - 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT etc...)
```

So that answers the first part, the second part of the answer is that its a known bug apparently in oracle 10g that you can't do arithmetic operations after the subquery in an update statement (duh!) so changing the above to

```
UPDATE VERSIONED Person SET groupsCount = - 1 + followingGroup.size WHERE id IN (SELECT etc...)
```

works just fine. phew-

Comment: here's the oracle thread about that bug- http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2192872

Answer (score 1):

The following is working on the 11.2.0.2 instance behind apex.oracle.com

```
create table person (id number, version number, groupscount number);

create table groupfollower (followerid number, followingid number);

insert into person values (1,1,0);
insert into person values (2,1,0);
insert into groupfollower values (1,2);


UPDATE Person
  SET version  =version+1,
  groupsCount=
  (SELECT COUNT(followingg1_.followerId)
     FROM GroupFollower followingg1_
    WHERE Person.id=followingg1_.followerId
  )-1
  WHERE id IN
  (SELECT groupfollo2_.followerId
     FROM GroupFollower groupfollo2_
    WHERE groupfollo2_.followingId=2
  )
```

Suggest you check that SQL in your version. It may be a Hibernate issue.

Comment: I've run this exact setup script and update statement, the error is the same - 

ora-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line:16 Column:4

     Line 16 is the 
")-1"

Comment: one correction, i'm still at 10g, oops - Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi

Comment: well now that is pretty messed up, if you put the subtraction of 1 infront of the subquery it runs just fine. looks like an oracle bug. anyway to override the way the size() function works in hibernate? other best practice for working around a db bug like this with hibernate?

Comment: should i create a new question with 10g in title?